# Regex: Negate capture group with logical or

Tags: html, regex, parsing, regular-language

I'm trying to use regex to filter forbidden HTML tags out of a given string. Yes I know, I'm supposed to use a parser instead but for this specific problem it's faster this way.

The idea is to whitelist every tag which is okay (e.g. `<span>, <b>, </br>`) and match forbidden ones. So far I came up with the following expression: `<\/?(?!(span|b|br)).\>`

It works well for single char tags like `<a>` but stuff like `<label>` does not work. I'd really appreciate some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: It should work with any tag. Use `<\/?(?!(label|span|br?)\b)[^>]*>`

Comment: No `<label>` is forbidden, exactly like `<a>`. The problem is that the expression matches only forbidden tags with a single char, not multiple chars like `<label>`

Comment: Maybe you should try `<\/?(?!(span|br?)\b)[^>]*>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will get tags while ignoring the span, br, b opening and closing tags.

It should even ignore those from the white list if they contain attributes.

```
<\/?(?!(?:span|br|b)(?: [^>]*)?>)[^>\/]*>
```

Comment: This works and the syntax is very convenient in my situation. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
/<(?!(\/?span|\/?b|\/?br)).*?>/g
```

[image]

Comment: Works as well! Thank you!